# Cosmos DB partition design

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I m new to Cosmos DB and I have a set of flat json files to migrate to cosmoDB

they look like that (customerID, albumId, and photoId are globaly unique):

```
{
    customerId: "xxx",
    albums : [
        {
            albumId: "yyyy",
            photos: [
                {
                   photoId: "zzzz"
                },
                ...    
            ]
         },
         ...
    ]
}
```

I was thinking to simply **create one container, and each partition is one customer**.

- the write updates are not frequent
- Queries are going to be like get album with all photos from customer account
- Some customer hardly use their account but some more. few thousand requests per day without going to very high numbers so I wonder if it breaks the rule of "evenly distribute load across partition"

Do you think I can use this simple design with success or should I break it in smaller documents?

Comment: It is impossible to say here for sure with the information provided. You need to work out most/all of the queries for your application to help determine the optimal partition key. I would read this article we wrote about how to model and choose a partition key for a blog platform. The steps on how to go about doing this are the same steps you should take when designing a data model and partition key strategy for Cosmos DB, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example Hope this helps.

Comment: Agree with @MarkBrown - this is unfortunately too broad for Stack Overflow. You'll probably want to try out different partitioning schemes and see how they work with your specific queries. Also note: you haven't shown any top-level `album` documents, so if you're searching for a specific album, this means searching every customer document, right? (searching the array to see if it contains an album id) Also, you've created an "unbounded array" scenario (too many albums could exceed a single document's limit).

Comment: thank you Mark very interesting read. Hello David it's always an album for a customer, so looking for the album id within the customer.

Both albums and photos are unbounded... albums in practices are between 0 and 100, photos can be between 0 and 10k!